# Display icon on hover over another object

Tags: html, css

I want my links to display a font-awesome icon next to them when hovered over. The whole line looks like this:

```
<a href="#" class="link">link</a> <span class="someicon"></span>
```

How do I make class "someicon" visible when class "link" is hovered over?

EDIT:

Thanks everybody, I came up with an even better solution. No need for extra classes and DOM elements:

```
.link:hover::after {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    content: "\00a0\f040";
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

This is basic CSS.

```css
.someicon {
  display: none;
}
.link:hover + .someicon {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">link</a>  <span class="someicon">i'm an icon</span>
```

Personally though I would make the icon *part* of the link so it can be clicked too!

```css
a span {
  opacity: 0;
}
a:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">link <span class="someicon">i'm an icon</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```css
.icon{
  visibility:hidden;
}
.link:hover+.icon{
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#" class="link">link</a> <span class="icon"><i class="icon-li icon-ok"></i></span>
```